# Stdout from spawnSync to express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

Newbie with Node so please bear with me.
Also I know this question has been asked before but I haven't figured out how to use it in my case so again, please do try to help.

What I'm trying to do -
Trying to get the images for a specific docker container in list format using express-handlebars.

Code -

```
app.get('/restore/:userid', async (req,res) => {
  let userid = req.params.userid
  let userData = await Users.findById(userid, async function(err, data) {
    let site = await data.docker.site.slice(8)
    let backupsRun = await spawnSync('sh', ['-c', `echo redhat237 | sudo -S docker images | grep ${site} | awk '{print $2}'`], {encoding: 'utf-8'})
    let backupsStdout = await backupsRun.stdout
    if (backupsRun.status != 0) {var getBackups = new Error("Cannot fetch Backups")}
    let backupsStdoutDecoded = await unescape(encodeURIComponent(backupsStdout))
    let backupsArr = await backupsStdoutDecoded.split("\n")
    /*for (var i = 0; i < backupsArr.length; i++) {
      var backups = await backupsArr[i].value
    }*/
    let backups = backupsArr
    try {
      console.log(backups + ' Try Block')
      await res.render('restore', {
        helpers: {
          userid: function () {return req.params.userid},
          site: site,
          backups: backups
        }
      })
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.getBackups) {
        res.send(e.getBackups)
      } else {
        res.send(e)
      }
    }
  })
}) //close restore get
```

I can see the output in console.log but it reads as 1 line with seemingly 1 index.

```
test.test.org-12-7-2021T12_13,test.test.org-12-07-21T12_10,test.test.org12-07-21T12_10,test.test.org, Try Block
```

My handlebars page -

```
<h1>Restore for {{site}} - </h1>
<ul>
  {{#each backups}}
  <li><p>{{this}}</p></li>
  {{else}}
  <h3>ERROR - No Backups or we couldn't retrieve your backups</h3>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<div>
  {{backups}} - Backups array in div
</div>
```

The strange thing is I can see the output in the div section which I had added for debugging, however I can't get the #each block to iterate.

From what I can understand from the following situation is that while split() is supposed to return an array of substrings for some reason that doesn't seem to be happening.

I even went and tried join() and toString() but it was the same result.
If I uncomment the for loop and run it with .value it returns "undefined" in the console.log.

If someone could please point out my mistake/s and help me with it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are `site` and `backups` meant to be in `helpers`?

Comment: What is the `unescape(encodeURIComponent(backupsStdout))` for?

Comment: Arrays are joined with a `,` when you use them as a string

Comment: @Matt,Yes site and backups are both meant to be in helpers

Comment: @Matt,
`unescape(encodeURIComponent(backupsStdout))` was a desperate attempt to change the encoding from utf-8 which I had used while running spawnSync.
I read in one of the answers that it might help hence the attemp.

What I read was that an array would follow the following format ["string", "string1"]....
The return that I get which I've posted above doesn't contain the `" "` marks, plus if I try to call the array using an index backups[<number>] It only works with the number 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `backups` and `site` to the parent object passed to `res.render`

```
res.render('restore', {
  helpers: {
    userid: function () {return req.params.userid},
  },
  site,
  backups,
  })
```

Then loop on the variable `{{#backups}}

```
<h1>Restore for {{site}} - </h1>
<ul>
  {{#each backups}}
  <li><p>{{this}}</p></li>
  {{else}}
  <h3>ERROR - No Backups or we couldn't retrieve your backups</h3>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<div>
  {{ backups }} - Backups array in div
</div>
```

#### More cleanup

When are arrays are converted to a string, they are joined with a `,`. The `console.log(backups + ' Try Block')` is doing this conversion.

Give the applications user access to run `sudo docker images` without a password via sudoers (or if you must, `sudo docker` but understand the [security implications](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) that the app has complete control of the host now)

Avoid using a shell when executing commands. Use dockers filter and output modifiers or process the output in JS where possible.

Only use `await` when calling an `async` function.

Setup an async function to run your docker commands, assuming this might be common.

```
const util = require('util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)

async function dockerCommand(docker_args) {
  try {
    console.log('Running docker', docker_args)
    const res = await exec(['sudo', 'docker', ...docker_args])
    return res
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error running docker', docker_args, e)
    throw e
  }
}
```

```
app.get('/restore/:userid', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userid = req.params.userid
    const userData = await Users.findById(userid)
    const site = userData.docker.site.slice(8)
    const { stdout, stderr } = await dockerCommand('images', `--filter=*:${site}*`, '--format={ .Tag }')
    const backups = stdout.split('\n')
    console.log('backups for site[%s]', site, backups)
    res.render('restore', {
      helpers: {
        userid: function () {return req.params.userid},
      },
      site,
      backups,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error retrieving backups', req.params.userid, e)
    res.send('Error retrieving backups')
  }
}) //close restore get
```

Comment: Hi @Matt!

Your answer definitely works, thanks a bunch but could you explain the working of passing the object directly instead of registering it as a helper?

Also to help with future debugging how can I get console.log to show the object as it is without converting it to a string?

My plan is to use visudo to provide passwordless sudo access only for the docker command, to mitigate security threats.

Definitely will implement the cleanup suggestions. Can I use the (docker_args) parameter as common even for other commands?

Comment: Last question I use res.send incase the command fails which is why I was using spawnSync, does the async function that you've suggested do the same, i.e stay on the same webpage so that I can send an error via res.send?

Comment: handlebars makes each object key accessible template. helpers sounds like it's for functions to call from the template, but it's been a while since I've used handlebars.

Comment: The `console` statement examples above are all setup to log objects. Notice how the string and the variables are separate arguments.

Comment: Notice how I restructured the handler to be all in a try/catch. Any errors will use the `catch` res send. If you have a custom error to handle, `throw` it and handle it in the catch